# How to do a SSH to another instance, after getting access to current instance using AWS SSM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-ssm

I am using AWS and we have a EC2 set up, which we can use AWS Session Manager with. I am able to gain access to this system, but from here I want to access other private EC2 instances.

```
Host A (Logged in via SSM)  ----> Host B
```

(In these instances, many others like Host B don't have SSM set up right now.)

From here I try, to

```
ssh ec2-user@HostB
```

but this fails cause, it requires a PEM file.

I have access to this file on my local machine, but can't figure out how to send that file to Host A so I can use it to SSH into Host B

Comment: Also make sure host B's Security Group allows inbound SSH from host A. And be aware of a new EC2 connect feature called [EC2 Instance Connect Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connect-using-eice.html).

Comment: A combination of this and creating a pem file on A worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy the contents of the PEM file to your clipboard. Then, use SSM to connect to the other instance and save it to a file.

You can run an editor (eg `vi`), or just use `cat >key.pem` then paste your clipboard and type `Ctrl-D`.

You'll also need to `chmod 600 key.pem`.

To connect, use:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@HostB
```

Another method is to copy the file to S3 and then download it from S3.

Comment: Reading the answer late. But this is exactly what I ended up doing.